# Airflow schedule single dag for multiple schedules throughout the day

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I want to have a single DAG to download data from an FTP, I don't need all the data in the FTP just certain files. The files get uploaded daily at certain times throughout the day and I want to retrieve these files shortly after they are available on the FTP site.

Ex FTP schedule:

```
/Data/US/XASE/yyyymmdd.csv #uploaded daily at 9:00 PM UTC
/Data/EU/TRWB/yyyymmdd.csv #uploaded daily at 1:00 PM UTC
...
/Data/EU/XEUR/yyyymmdd.csv #uploaded daily at 11:00 AM UTC
```

How can I set the scheduler in the dag so that I can copy the data from the FTP site as they are uploaded and not have a separate dag for each upload time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have three options for scheduling here.

**Option 1**

You run exactly at 11AM,1PM,9PM UTC with the following schedule `0 11,13,21 * * *`. Or maybe 5 mins after the full hour to add some buffer (`5 11,13,21 * * *`).

**Option 2**

You run the DAG more regularly and check if the files are available and then download them within the Task. This makes sense if there is a higher chance that the file upload is delayed.

For example `*/10 10-22 * * *` would run every 10 minutes between 10:00-22:00.

**Option 3**

You schedule a DAG once per day (`@once`) and then work with [TimeDeltaSensor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_modules/airflow/sensors/time_delta_sensor.html). I think this option is least preferable as you have a lot of tasks just "waiting" - which can block the execution of other airflow tasks.

Besides that it also depends heavily how you want to handle the download from the FTP itself.

I guess you could create a task for every file to download per day and put a task based on [BranchPythonOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html#branching)  in front to avoid trying to download the same file multiple times.

Or you put the whole logic into a PythonOperator including a logic that just downloads certain files based on `execution_date`.

Comment: Both of these options would overload the FTP server

Comment: It would be good to understand which operator you plan to use. Otherwise it's hard to give any hints or tips. I adapted my answer a bit.

Comment: Option 3! `TimeDeltaSensor` is exactly what i needed